# How to increase the font size for Smart Capture fields in SFMC with <textarea> code?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture, textarea

I've created a SmartCapture in SFMC CloudPage. I want to increase the font size of the field input i.e., when someone fills in their details, that's the font size I want to increase.

[image]

I've used the following code

*<textarea rows="2" cols="77" input="" type="text" name="Employer" data-field-type="Text" **font-size="19px"** required="required" data-validation-message="Please fill out this field.>*

Some other variations I've tried include:

- font-family="inherit" font-size="inherit"
- font-size="20"
- size="20"
- fontsize="20", and many more.

But nothing seems to work with the ***textarea*** code. Any recommendations to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the attribute style like this

```
<textarea style="font-size: 18px"> whatever</textarea>
```